# jquery prettyphoto problem

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery prettyphoto in my project. for a image gallery when i click an image, it takes long time to load the prettyphoto, because it loads all image of the gallery to show thumbnails on it. I want to show the thumbnails but don't like taking long time. I have a thumbnail folder for the gallery which are small size files. If I were able to load those thumbnails in the prettyphoto it would take less time. I tried but could not find where to change that thumbnail directory manually. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the source code for the demos, it looks like you need to specify the thumbnail image in the markup:

```
<ul class="gallery">
    <li>
        <a title="This is the description" rel="prettyPhoto" href="/wp-content/themes/NMFE/images/fullscreen/2.jpg">
            <img src="/wp-content/themes/NMFE/images/thumbnails/t_2.jpg" alt="This is the title" width="50" height="50">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The link points to the full version, but the `<img>` `src` attribute points to the thumbnail.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it’s loading all the images is because of the overlay_gallery.
You can try to disable it and it should speed things up, it’s a setting you can customize.
view sourceprint?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto(

            {

                overlay_gallery: false /* If set to true, a gallery will overlay the fullscreen image on mouse over */

            });

 });

</script>
```